# Angular post method did not receive response from Spring boot app

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot

Did not understand why similar methods do not have the same behavior.

I have two methods for autorization in angular:

```
login(loginForm: LoginForm): Observable<JwtInfo> {
    return this.http.post<JwtInfo>(URL + 'login', loginForm, httpOptions);
  }

  reg(regForm: RegForm): Observable<any> {
    console.log(regForm.username + ' ' + regForm.password);
    return this.http.post(URL + 'reg', regForm, httpOptions);
  }
```

And subscribe methods for them:

```
login(data) {
    const loginForm: LoginForm = new LoginForm(data.username, data.password);
    this.authService.login(loginForm).subscribe((response: JwtInfo) => {
      this.tokenStorage.saveToken(response.accessToken);
      this.tokenStorage.saveUserName(response.username);
      this.tokenStorage.saveAutorities(response.authorities);
      window.location.reload();
      },
      error => this.infoMessage = error.error.message);
  }

reg(data) {
    const regForm: RegForm = new RegForm(data.username, data.password);
    console.log(regForm.username);
    this.authService.reg(regForm).subscribe(response => {
      console.log('Response received');
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      this.infoMessage = response;
      },
      error => this.infoMessage = error.error.message);
  }
```

Spring Boot api for them:

```
@PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody LoginForm loginForm) {
        ...// Bla bla bla
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(token, userPrincipal.getUsername(), userPrincipal.getAuthorities()));
    }

    @PostMapping("/reg")
    public ResponseEntity<?> register(@RequestBody RegForm regForm) {
        ...// Bla bla bla
        return ResponseEntity.ok("User registered successfully!");
    }
```

The login method works good, I got respose and a code execute in subscribe(response => bla bla). BUT a code in the subscribe(response => bla bla) of the method "reg" do not execute, although the service save a new user and there is not samething wrong in console. But why?O_o They are almost the same!

Thanks for attention and help)

Comment: Did you tried to test the register api with postman ? to check if it was front-end or back-end problem

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue once when I was sending String as response may be try something else instead of sending

ResponseEntity.ok("User registered successfully!");

try it like ResponseEntity.ok(create some object and set that string to it);